# Average of Normally Distributed Variables (Probability)

Tags: probability

I have worked through a solution to the following practice problem. I am wondering whether my below solution is correct, and if not, could anyone provide the correct analysis?

The question is:

According to the empirical rule, 68.26% of the observations of any normal random variable lie within one standard deviation from its mean. So, if 10 such random variables (n = 10) are averaged what is the probability of averages being in one standard deviation from the means?

So, I know the distribution is normal with $N\sim(\mu,\frac {\sigma^2}{n})$ such that $n=10$.

The Z-score formula states:

$Z=\frac {X-\mu}{\sigma}$

Thus I substitute the averaged variance and get:

$$Z=\frac {X-\mu}{\sigma_{\bar{x}}}=\frac {x-\mu}{\frac {\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac {\sqrt{n}(x-\mu)}{\sigma}$$

Because (through empirical rule):

$$\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)=0.6826$$

Then the probability that the averages are in one standard deviation from the mean is:

$$\Phi(\sqrt{10})-\Phi(-\sqrt{10})=0.9992-0.0008=0.9984$$

I am not too sure if that's correct and would appreciate any help if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

$$$$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{10}$ is a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$
then $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$

Here is a systematic way to obtain the probability you seek:
$$P(\mu - \sigma \le \bar X \le \mu + \sigma)
= P(-\sigma \le \bar X - \mu \le \sigma)\\
= P\left(-\frac{\sigma}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\sigma}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
= P(-\sqrt{n} \le Z \le \sqrt{n}) = \Phi(\sqrt{n}) - \Phi(-\sqrt{n}) = \cdots,$$
where $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

Computation in R statistical software (or you could use printed standard normal CDF tables):

```
pnorm(sqrt(10)) - pnorm(-sqrt(10))  # in R 'pnorm' is standard normal CDF
## 0.9984346
```

As @zhoraster says, you got the right answer (+1). But with this systematic approach, you won't
have to *wonder* if you got it right.